# How to exclude some services like login, register from interceptor Angular 5, HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor, angular-httpclient

i wanted to exclude some services using interceptor.

**app.module.js**

```
providers: [
    UserService,
    RolesService,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: TokenInterceptor,
        multi: true
      },
],
```

**Login.service.ts**

```
return this.httpClient.post(this.appUrl + '/oauth/token', body.toString(), { headers, observe: 'response' })
.map((res: Response) => {
  const response = res.body;
  this.storeToken(response);
  return response;
})
.catch((error: any) => {
  ErrorLogService.logError(error);
  return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
  });
}
```

Comment: you need to inject that servcie , what is problem in that ?

Comment: Provide the interceptor only in modules where you need it, then the http requests of the other modules are excluded from the interceptor. Might even be possible per component, as each component has it's own injector (providers).

Comment: @Fussel make an answer from that

Comment: Thanks @Fussel, it will solve the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To give this an answer not only in comments as requested ;-)

To exclude some services (or even the same services used in different components) from an interceptor it's best to split your application into modules and provide the interceptor only in modules where it's needed. For example after logging in or inside of an admin area.

The interceptor may be even provided for single components using the `@Component` declaration's `providers` property.

Comment: Hey Fussel can you provide an example of how to do this? I tried importing the interceptor into a specific module but still seems to be site wide. Your recommendation is interesting.

Comment: This would work, but it's not the smartest approach to the problem: if you have a large application you would have to refactor all the modules in your app, and that would take a lot of time.
Please consider @DragoRaptor's answer below. It provides an approach that doesn't require touching all modules in your app

Comment: @AndreaGherardi while I agree to some points of the awnser below consider having several modules which are not required to attach a token / or a different interceptor, do you really want to exclude all of these with a regular expression? That would be way less intuitive and more error prone - in my opinion. If you have many modules as you say, you could consider moving them into one parent module and add the interceptor there for example. For most apps the awnser below will do, but especially for large apps... well as I said.

Comment: We usually search for a global and unique way to handle all our requests, and we don't really want to have to separate our control by modules.

Comment: Seconding L1ghtk3ira. This doesn't work for me. My interceptor is only in one of my submodules and it's being applied to all HTTP requests.

Comment: @user3658800 Better open a new question with what you tried, I don't have any code using this atm.

Comment: @Fussel already did, no answers yet: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60386852/3658800

Answer (score 46):

Although [Fussel's answer](/a/49747272) works, it's often not good practice to include the interceptor service in every component module. It's counter intuitive and counter productive. We want the interceptor in one place and work for all HTTP requests.
One way is to exclude the header binding in the `intercept()` function based on the URL.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const re = /login/gi;
  // Exclude interceptor for login request
  if (req.url.search(re) === -1 ) {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`
      }
    });
  }
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

Comment: So the **re** `variable` which is the `/login/gi;` url will ignore the token of the headers and proceed the request right?

Comment: I disagree. I find Fussel's answer more correct and not unintuitive, as yours creates a hidden dependency of the interceptor on the endpoints. What if I create a new endpoint I want to exclude from the http interceptor scope? I'd need to remember to update the HttpInterceptor.

Answer (score 4):

I had to solve this same.
The division into modules is very expensive for me.
And the #DragoRaptor solution is not suitable when you have several points where you need to "jump" the interceptor

My solution is unorthodox, but maybe it will serve someone else.

It simply consists of:

1. Include one more parameter in the request
2. Check for this parameter in the interceptor
3. Remove the parameter

**Invocation example**

```
    public searchPersons(term: string): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get('person/', { params: { dni: term, spinner: 'no' } });
    }
```

**Interceptor example**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

// check if you have the parameter 'spinner'
    const spinner = request.params.get('spinner');
    if (spinner && spinner === 'no') {

// remove parameter
      request.params.delete('spinner');

// jump the interceptor
      return next.handle(request);
    }

// Execute interceptor

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpBackend for this. Example is given below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NoheaderService {

 private httpClient: HttpClient;
  constructor( handler: HttpBackend) { 
     this.httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
     }

   fetchInsta(username) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         this.httpClient.get(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`)
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
           resolve(response);
             },reject);
               })
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was able to solve it like this:

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler: Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

// You can retrieve the url or a part in order to filter them
       if (request.url.slice(0, 20) != 'https://site.to.exclude') {
      request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
             'content-type': 'application/json',
            // or your header specific add to the interceptor
          }
        });
      }
     else {
//  interceptor does not add specific header
      return next.handle(request)
      }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem. Once implemented interceptor hunt all http requests anyway. It was in my code about if i have, or not access token. If I haven't than interceptors token parametar has to be set to ""(empty string). Than everything goes.
In the interceptor fn code it seems like this:

```
       intercept(
          request: HttpRequest<any>,
          next: HttpHandler**strong text**
       ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        //how to update the request Parameters
        **let token : string;
        let currentUser : any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser){
            token = currentUser.access_token;
        }else{token = ""}**

        console.log("Token dobavljen sa localStorage.getItem:   ", token);
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
        }

        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

        request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });

        //logging the updated Parameters to browser's console
        console.log("Before making api call : ", token);

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
                event => {
                    //logging the http response to browser's console in case of a success
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log("api call success :", event);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    //logging the http response to browser's console in case of a failuer
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    console.log("api call error :", event);
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    //}
}
```