# Why are my Observables not being subscribed to in my code?

Tags: angular, rxjs

The below code is an implementation of the `intercept` method that belongs to the `HttpInterceptor` interface. This particular code intercepts each HTTP request going out of my application so that it can determine that the JWT token stored in browser local storage is valid. If they are, headers (the authentication and authorization tokens) are added to the HTTP request and the request is sent.

I'm trying to extend the code so that before the headers are added, the code first checks to ensure the integrity of the JWT is sound and that it is not expired or has been modified in any way. If it has, then the code should retrieve a new JWT token from an API endpoint and then validate the new token.

The issue is that the first subscription, `authTokenStream.pipe(take(1)).subscribe` never seems to be triggered. When I step through the debugger each line is executed up until this one and then after that it never steps inside the subscription. Instead the method finishes and then begins again at the top for the next HTTP request.

I thought this might be something to do with microtasks and the event loop, but if that was the case I'd expect subscription code to be actually executed. Instead the code just executes the lines above it and then finishes it. At no point does it reach the breakpoints inside the subscription code.

The `authTokenStream` object is valid, as I've checked in the debugger. It's not as if it's undefined or anything.

```
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let jwtToken: string = this._authService.getAuthorizationToken();

    if (!this.checkJwtTokenIsValid(jwtToken)) { //Invalid token, get new one
      const authTokenStream = this._authService.getAuthorizationToken$();
      authTokenStream.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(newToken => {  //<-- Debugger gets to here and moves onto next HTTP request. 

        if(!this.checkJwtTokenIsValid(newToken)) //Still invalid
        {
          this._authService.signOut("jwtInvalid"); //Don't log out, get new token
          return;
        }

        req = this.addHeaders(req);
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
          catchError(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
              this._authService.signOut("unauthorized");
            }
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
              this._authService.signOut("expired");
            }
            return throwError(error);
          })
        );
      });
      return;
    }

    req = this.addHeaders(req);
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          this._authService.signOut("unauthorized");
        }
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
          this._authService.signOut("expired");
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );

  }

getAuthorizationToken$(): Observable<string> {
    return this._httpClient.get<string>(this._configService.getConfig().tokenApi);
  }
```

Comment: @WenHaoWu I have actually included this function at the bottom of my code snippet. It is async as it's making a call to an external API.

Comment: then you have to wait for that to finish before doing anything else, otherwise the line of code that you are trying to execute will be skipped.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. That isn't the problem as the Observable is returned. The problem is that the Observable is never subscribed to in the next line.

Comment: I apologize, I'm still trying to understand your code. So the flow would be that every http request gets intercepted, check the token, if expired, refresh, if not, send the http request. I'm assuming the function this._authService.signOut("jwtInvalid"); is also an async function? If that's the case, then I think all you need is put your http request inside the promise of that async function for this to work? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the token is invalid, your code will always hit the `return;` line, after the subscribtion.
2. You return from inside the `subscribe` method, which is a void method. So nothing will happen, because there is nothing that will subscribe to the new request.

To fixe the problem you have to set up a propper async handling.

```
if (!this.checkJwtTokenIsValid(jwtToken)) { //Invalid token, get new one
  const authTokenStream = this._authService.getAuthorizationToken$();

  return authTokenStream.pipe(
    take(1), 
    switchMap(newToken => {

    if(!this.checkJwtTokenIsValid(newToken)) //Still invalid
    {
      this._authService.signOut("jwtInvalid"); //Don't log out, get new token
      return EMPTY;
    }

    req = this.addHeaders(req);

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          this._authService.signOut("unauthorized");
        }
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
          this._authService.signOut("expired");
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }))
}
```

The switchMap operator is now subscribing to your tokenStream and the returning the new request observable. In this way the request pipe still has a request to subscribe on.
For more info about switchMap [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html).

Comment: With your code I'm now getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: Upps, sorry I blind typed it. Could you provide a Stackblitz or something else?

Comment: I think the problem is that the code is working and the tokenRequest is being triggerd BUT you are emitting a new http request for the token, which is also intercepted. So you get stuck there.

Comment: Make sure that the token request does not require a token ^^

Comment: Now you mention it, that's possibly the reason why I'm getting stack overflow errors. Is there a way to prevent the HTTP request to my API from being caught by the interceptor?

Comment: There a several ways. I would recommend to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732337/7600725