# HttpInterceptor inside a component affecting all the App HttpRequests

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have a library that contains a component. This component has an HttpInterceptor for his HttpRequests that set a header for each request.

My problem is that when I use the component in another project, the HttpInterceptor set the headers for all the HttpRequests of the project, and not only for the component's HttpRequests.

Any ideas of how can my problem get solved.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Interceptors must all be declared in a single module, where that module must also include the `HttpClientModule`. Because of this, the only feasible solution would be to not set the headers in your interceptor, based on some condition. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50732337/9632621).

Comment: As mentioned, you have to add conditions to suppress interceptors calling unnecessarily. That's the only way.

Comment: Yeah thats what I'll do. Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you CANNOT have separate interceptors in an application. I verified it through this - 
[Interceptors-check](https://stackblitz.com/edit/interceptors-check)

I trialed by

- Having Parent & Child Modules separately imported into App component.
- Having Child Module imported into Parent component and Parent into App.
- I moved all the services inside the modules (even if I had to duplicate code)
- I moved the `HttpClientModule` from Parent and Child modules into App module.

> Seems like when we register interceptor(s), it get's hooked to the
>   entire application and not just that module.

**Note**: I DELETED my previous answer where I mentioned the below text and example (as my assumption went WRONG).

If you want to have separate interceptors for different components, then wrap them in separate modules and import one of them in another, based on your preference.

```
// child.module.ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ChildComponent],
  providers: [{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorTwo,
      multi: true,
  }],
  exports: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ChildModule{}


// parent.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ... ,
    ChildModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ... , {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorOne,
      multi: true,
    }],
  ...
})
export class ParentModule{}
```